# How to disable the declared value on Fedex?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, fedex

When I estimate on Fedex website show a value, when I use my store is another. Seems like my store is using a declared value, how can I remove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If will be testing is on this file below, if was a permanent change create a module to rewrite.

File: **app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php**

**Line 335 and 360** that have this code:

```
'Amount' => $r->getValue(),
'Currency' => $this->getCurrencyCode()
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent a day trying to find the same answer for 2.3. I finally found the solution and posted to my github.

https://github.com/dubrod/magento-2-fedex-preference